# Fetchmail to keep original date/time

Tags: email, fetchmail

I'm setting up my own IMAP and I need to gather emails received during the last 9 years in my own server (and to continuously synchronize from a few email boxes).

I have successfully set up fetchmail with a test account on an empty mailbox. Whenever I send mail to the target mailbox, it will be picked up via POP3 into my box.
**But** I discovered that the message I'm delivered into Windows Mail shows the date/time when `fetchmail` ran. This can be appropriate for new mail, but really inappropriate for history tracking.

My `.fetchmailrc` file **currently** * shows

```
set invisible

poll pop.fastwebnet.it proto imap
        user "redacted" pass "redacted" fetchall
        mda "/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver"
```

My inbox is configured using Postfix & Dovecot with `Maildir` format. I chose POP3 for fetchmail because it will delete the message once synchronized to maildir.

### How can I tell `fetchmail` that new mail dropped into Maildir must match exactly what found on server, with reference to *date and time*?

I mean, if I went to synchronize my history from `anotherbox@example.org` that accumulated 9 years of mail, all of them will be dated today!

For example, I sent myself a test email at about 14:59 to `redacted@fastwebnet.it`, opened the webmail at `fastwebnet.it` to confirm that 14:59 was the "official" time, then ran `fetchmail` from my server at 15:30. Windows Mail showed that the email's time was 15:30 instead of 14:59.

#### Updates

From the comment and by reading the documentation, it looks clear that fetchmail normally adds a `Received` header at the top of the email so the client will detect the mail is brand new.

I also ran `fetchmail` in verbose mode, this time using IMAP. It seems that by default it drops mail via SMTP, so that's where the problem lies. If my server receives a mail via SMTP to be dropped into Maildir, it will assume that the email is brand new.

*I have updated my questions from the original writing

Comment: fetchmail does not rewrite the `Date` field. It puts the maildrop date into a `Received` field at the top of the headers, but not in `Date`, which is the one that is normally displayed by a MUA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the date exposed to the user by Windows Mail does not come from the `Date` header field, but rather from the latest `Received` field (`Received` fields are primarily meant to trace a message through delivery gateways, as mentioned in [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.7.2) and [RFC5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.7)).

When fetchmail delivers a message, even with the `mda` option (not using SMTP), by default it adds its own `Received` field with the current date and time.

Fortunately it provides an option to disable this:

> The **--invisible** option (keyword: set invisible) tries to make
> fetchmail invisible. Normally, fetchmail behaves like any other MTA
> would -- it generates a Received header into each message describing
> its place in the chain of transmission, and tells the MTA it forwards
> to that the mail came from the machine fetchmail itself is running on.
> If the invisible option is on, the Received header is suppressed and
> fetchmail tries to spoof the MTA it forwards to into thinking it came
> directly from the mailserver host.

I believe you want to combine this option with a non-SMTP delivery, for instance with `--mda /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver`. Otherwise the SMTP server would probably add its own `Received` field after fetchmail.

Comment: Tried to add "set invisible" at the top of the .fetchmailrc, is that the correct place? Both your advices didn't work (yet)

Comment: Ok then, I tried "set invisible" after the "poll" statement and I'm fetching groups of 2 mails at a time. When they are delivered they look like new mail (no problem) but seems that the dates are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since the scope of the question was to perform an "initial" hystorical migration of mailbox, here are different `brute force` approaches: move emails from old IMAP to new inbox. From then on, fetchmail daemon will work fine with *new* mail

#### Via client (e.g. Outlook)

Synchronize both mailboxes, select all (or groups of) emails and drag&drop or cut&paste them into the new Inbox. This will take some time and manual work, but can do none or little damage, especially if you move emails in groups

#### Via dump

Since I have access to the server, a tool such as [imap2maildir](https://github.com/rtucker/imap2maildir/) can dump an IMAP box into a Maildir compatible box. Merging the original Maildir with the new one initializes message collection correctly

#### Via any other specific commercial tool

There are plenties of tools made for IMAP migration/synchronization. There are even online tools, to which you must provide your box password (for your security you may change the password to a temporary one during migration), and you must trust the service not to keep your personal data.